# vector<wstring> as Return value and Parameter

Tags: c++, function, vector

I want to create some modules for my program. I want to call a function and pass a vector as a parameter. The return value should also be a vector.

My code looks like this

```
main.cpp
//BlueSmart.cpp : Definiert den Einstiegspunkt für die Konsolenanwendung.
#include "stdafx.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Irprops.lib")



BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS m_bt_find_radio = {
sizeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS)
};

BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO m_bt_info = {
sizeof(BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO),
0,
};

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS m_search_params = {
sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
1,
0,
1,
1,
1,
15,
NULL
};

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO m_device_info = {
sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO),
0,
};

HANDLE m_radio = NULL;
HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND m_bt = NULL;
HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND m_bt_dev = NULL;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **args) {

while(true) {
m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio);

do {
  localBluetoothDevices ();

  m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;
  ::ZeroMemory(&m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
  m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);
  m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&m_search_params, &m_device_info);

  vector<wstring> vec;
  int m_device_id = 0;
  do {
   wostringstream tmp;
   ++m_device_id;
   //Something like this <----------------------------------------
   externBluetoothDevices (vec);
   //Something like this <----------------------------------------

      wprintf(L"********************************************************************** \n");
   wprintf(L"\tDevice %d:\r\n", m_device_id);
   wprintf(L"\t\tName: %s\r\n", m_device_info.szName);
   wprintf(L"\t\tAddress: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\r\n", m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5]);
   wprintf(L"====================================================================== \n");


   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    tmp << hex << m_device_info.Address.rgBytes [i];
    if (i < 5)
     tmp << L':';
   }

   vec.push_back(tmp.str());

  } while(BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, &m_device_info));


  BluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev);
  //Sleep(10*1000*60);
  Sleep(10000);

} while(BluetoothFindNextRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio));
BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt);
}
return 0;
}

//Lokal verfügbare bzw. angeschlossene Bluetooth-Devices
void localBluetoothDevices (){
  int m_radio_id = 0;
  m_radio_id++;
  BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, &m_bt_info);      
  //Lokaler Bluetoothadapter
  wprintf(L"====================================================================== \n");
  wprintf(L"Local Device Nr. %d\n", m_radio_id);
  wprintf(L"\tName: %s\r\n", m_bt_info.szName);
  wprintf(L"\tAddress: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\r\n",      m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[0], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[1], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[2], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[3], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[4], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[5]);

 }

//Extern verfügbare bzw. Bluetooth-Devices
 vector<wstring> externBluetoothDevices (vector<wstring> &vec){
return vec;
 }
```

stdafx.h

```
 #pragma once

 #include "targetver.h"

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <tchar.h>
 #include <winsock2.h>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <bthdef.h>
 #include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <conio.h>

 void localBluetoothDevices ();
 vector<wstring> externBluetoothDevices (vector<wstring>);
```

It says that vector is not a known type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include <vector>? Did you say using namespace std; or similar? Did you really call your function extern? Always a good idea when asking about compiler error messages to post the actual code, not mistyped excerpts from it. And to say which line has the error.

Comment: `extern` is a C++ reserved keyword and cannot be used, please [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) for a list.

Comment: yes i included <vector>... also Im using namesspace std... Ow, extern is only a sample name. it also can called somthing else. Sorry

Comment: @user1557170, OK lets see the real code.

Comment: @user1557170 Small things like that are important. Please show your actual code.

Comment: @user1557170 Still not your real code. Post the code, not a sample, not **...**, the real actual code that you can see in front of you on your computer screen but we cannot.

Comment: Make sure you put `#include <vector>` and `using namespace std;` at the top of both the header files and source files.

Comment: Actually `using namespace std;` in  a *header* file is a very bad idea. I would recommend `std::vector` in the header file at least.

Comment: +1 john, beat me to that by 18 seconds. =P

Comment: great. more code. now put stdafx.h in the post and we'll finally have an answer for you.

Comment: so there a my full code!

Comment: No it isn't your full code. put stdafx.h contents up there as well.

Comment: I posted everything now!

Comment: There you go. now watch the answers.

Comment: also I get some warning cause of the pragma... Don't know why :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stdafx.h replace

```
vector<wstring> externBluetoothDevices (vector<wstring>);
```

with

```
std::vector<std::wstring> externBluetoothDevices (std::vector<std::wstring>);
```

Basically the issue was although you put `using namespace std;` in your cpp file that doesn't count in your header file which is before the using declaration is seen.

Also note that your defintion in the cpp file is different. In the cpp file you have a reference

```
vector<wstring> externBluetoothDevices (vector<wstring>&);
```

Decide which you really want.

Comment: why the replacement with std:: ?!

Comment: The real name of the class is `std::vector`. `using namespace std;` allows you to miss out the std:: part. But you don't have `using namespace std;' in your header file, it only comes later. Don't think this means you should put 'using namespace std; in your header file though, that is a bad idea.

Comment: u know why I get some pragma warning ?!

Comment: @user1557170 would have to see the warning, but thats another issue.

Comment: Sorry no. (especially since you don't say what the warning is).

Comment: I'm sorry. I just won't get on your nerves ... I have for warnings about an uknown pragma:Warnung 1 warning C4068: Unbekanntes Pragma c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\bluetoothapis.h 863

Comment: @user1557170 Is this being compiled using VC++ ? or are you using mingw and gcc or some other compiler?

Comment: I have a vague recollection that the comment pragma was removed by MS a few years ago. (But I might be remembering wrong).

Comment: @john it wasn't. in fact, it is how libs are auto-linked via compiler-switch. (`#pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")`). regardless you answered the question. =P

Comment: I don't understand. What should I do to get out the warnings ?!

Comment: @WhozCraig, hmm must have been some other pragma then.

Comment: @user1557170 Any reason you can't delete it. I mean what do you think it's doing for you?

Comment: @user1557170 its s different issue the one one for this post. If you want to trace it down, I suggest you open a new question (after marking this one resolved, see the green check at the top of this answer) and be prepared to show in your question the contents of the header file (specifically the #pragma in the header) that is causing your grief. Also do some web-searching for that pragma, the warning message, and possible reasons first.

Comment: @user1557170 Hang on a minute, the unknown pragma you are talking about is different. I have no idea what to do about an unknown pragma in  bluetoothapis.h

Comment: @john exactly. it is a different issue, and deserves a different approach (question).

Comment: Ok, I will now try to solve the problem by myself during the night - like pragmas :-) Thanks for the great suppurt! Stackoverflow is a great fuq!!!

Comment: btw the unknown pragma is `#pragma deprecate(...)` and a litany of others. it is supposed to be **deprecated**; not deprecate. Known issue with MS.

Comment: @john lol. hardest i've worked for someone else 25pts in a *long* time =P thank god that's over.

Comment: @WhozCraig Cheers for that. I'll return the favour some day.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a pointer of a vector.

Comment: How does that answer the question?